# Need to create new row in second column if there is a comma in the content and first column need to be autosized usign Java Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Consider there are two columns in excel:Name and Country
There must be two countries for a name, like:(In name column)Tom and (in Country) India,US.
What i want is, in the above mentioned case, if there is a comma in the Country column then it should be displayed in the next row of the same column and the Name column should be resized as per both the country

And the name should be centred to both the countries as displayed in the image below

[Actual data and Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Tl2.png)

Comment: Use a template xlsx to format the workbook according to your formatting needs. Then open that template to populate the data. Sometimes it's easier that way.

Comment: But i need to code it in java using Apache POI and this should be done before the generation of xlsx file.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: static String[] source= new String [8000];
String[] s1=source;
int l=s1.length; 
while(s1.toString().contains(","))
{
 String s2=StringUtils.substring(s1.toString(), l+2);
 if(s2 != null)
 {
  int createCellat=13;
  row=sheet.createRow(createCellat);
  cell.setCellValue(source.length-1);
  cell=row.createCell(1);
 }
}

So basically, this is what im using @zawhtut